# What does the 'shutdown=' in a hibernate.connection.url mean?

Tags: hibernate, jdbc

What does the 'shutdown=' in  `hibernate.connection.url` mean? Are the only options true and false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hibernate.connection.url` just specify the JDBC URL that hibernate will use to connect to the database.

The properties inside the JDBC URL has nothing to do with Hibernate. It is only related to the JDBC driver which every JDBC  driver has their own set of properties to specify additional JDBC driver behavior.

For example ,JDBC driver of HSQLDB has `shutdown` properties (true or false)  to specify whether to shut down the database when the last connection is closed.

From [official HSQLDB  documentation](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html):

> If this property is true, when the last connection to a database is
>   closed, the database is automatically shut down. The property takes
>   effect only when the first connection is made to the database. This
>   means the connection that opens the database. It has no effect if used
>   with subsequent connections.
>
> This command has two uses. One is for test suites, where connections
>   to the database are made from one JVM context, immediately followed by
>   another context. The other use is for applications where it is not
>   easy to configure the environment to shutdown the database. Examples
>   reported by users include web application servers, where the closing
>   of the last connection coincides with the web app being shut down.
>
> ```
> jdbc:hsqldb:file:enrolments;shutdown=true
> ```

Answer (score 0):

It sets the shutdown parameter in the connection URL. If set to **true**, the database shuts down when the connection issued with this URL is closed.